# Post to Facebook button does not work after confirming like

Tags: facebook, facebook-like

I'm pretty new to web development, so I started by created a blog in rails here,
[blog website.](http://www.phillypham.com)
I was playing around with open graph meta tags, so I was liking and unliking, repeatedly. It seems that I'm blacklisted now, which I'm okay with. Unfortunately, after confirming a like, I'm unable to post a message to facebook. I just press the "Post to Facebook" button and nothing happens.

I'm inclined to think this behavior is a bug or intentional, but perhaps I'm missing something?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you should type something in as a message, and it works... check it out, u'll see that this will not be posted on your wall as a "Share" post, but in fact as a "Like" action of a page.